# How can I iterate through a Date/Time column in a CSV file when the dates are different for each file

Tags: java, csv

So the format of the Date/Time column in the CSV file looks like this:

```
csv[0]                      csv[1]      
2014-06-02T00:00:00         someNumericalData
2014-06-03T00:00:00         etc...
```

Depending on the file I'm working with, it could be 2013, 2012 etc. I want to be able to get the numerical data in the other column for each day of data. So all the numerical data for 2014-06-02 will be in one array/list, then when I hit the next date, I store the data in a new array/list.

I can iterate through the CSV and get data fine, it's just checking the dates that's bugging me. If anyone can help or point me in the right direction about how to tackle this it would be great. 
(Note: Only the data is relevant, time doesn't matter)

Comment: It's not clear what aspect of "checking the dates" is a problem. Are you finding it hard to parse the string? (Look at SimpleDateFormat, or ideally use Joda Time...)

Comment: I just wasn't sure how to go about iterating through, and how to know when I've reached a new day. I've never heard of Joda Time but it looks very useful, so I'm going to try and use that. Thanks Jon

Comment: Could you please provide an extended example to illustrate what you mean by _I want to be able to get the numerical data in the other column for each day of data. So all the numerical data for 2014-06-02 will be in one array/list, then when I hit the next date, I store the data in a new array/list._ **?**

Comment: There are multiple columns in the CSV file. The date and time are in the first (0) column, and I am interested in float values (e.g. 0.765) which are in another column (5). I can currently go through the CSV file, and get all the double values from one column into its own list. What I want to do, is have all the values for each day in their own list. So all the values for 2014-06-02 will be in their own list.

Comment: You could use a HashMap (Day -> List of Floats). Just extract the day from the date (e.g. using SimpleDateFormat) and use the HashMap to get the appropriate day-list to append to. (BTW, your example is confusing as it shows only one value per day)

Comment: Sorry about the example. In the real file there could be fifty entries before the dates change. Your suggestion seems like a good approach, so I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: @HarryV Ok, so I agree that a `TreeMap<Date, List<Float>>` will do. That's why I asked you to extend your example: I suspected that there'd be more than one entry for a given day but your example above jumped a whole day.

Comment: @tobias_k I went with your suggestion of using a HashMap. I currently have it like so: HashMap<List<Date>, List<Double>>. One Key Value pair in the map would look like this.

    `[Mon Jun 2 16:00:00 GMT 2014] => [0.1234]`

There are a few hundred more entries which continue on in the same format. My approach now would be to iterate over the map and say 
"whenever I get to a new day (e.g Tuesday), take all the values up until now and put them in a new list, then continue on until the end."

Would you be able to help in doing that?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is by iterating over the map, if(day = day.previous), then list.add(value), else if(day = day.prev+1) then newList.add(value). I'm unsure if this is feasible as I haven't worked with HashMaps much before.

Comment: @HarryV No need to bother with the previous day... wait, I'm writing up an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is to use a `Map` for grouping values for the same date. You can use just a `HashMap`, or better use a `TreeMap` so the entries are sorted by date.

I don't want to bother with reading CSV input, so I'll just put some example data into another map (those don't have to be ordered). Adapting this to your CSV approach should be trivial.

```
Map<String, Double> ungroupedCsv = new TreeMap<>();
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-02T00:01:00", 1.1);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-02T00:02:00", 1.2);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-02T03:00:00", 1.3);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-02T04:20:00", 1.4);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-03T00:00:01", 2.1);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-03T00:01:00", 2.2);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-03T00:11:00", 2.3);
ungroupedCsv.put("2014-06-03T01:10:00", 2.4);
```

Next we need two date formats: one for the original format, with date and time, and one with date only:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat dateOnly = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The grouped dates are stored in a `Map`, mapping the date-only string in above format to lists of numerical values from the original list.

```
Map<String, List<Double>> grouped = new TreeMap<>();
```

Now we can iterate all the entries in the original map (or CSV file), re-code the date format, and add the value to the respective date-list (or create that list if it does not yet exist).

```
for (String key : ungroupedCsv.keySet()) {
    String date = dateOnly.format(dateTime.parse(key));
    if (! grouped.containsKey(date)) {
        grouped.put(date, new ArrayList<Double>());
    }
    grouped.get(date).add(ungroupedCsv.get(key));
}
System.out.println(grouped);
```

Output:

```
{2014-06-02=[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4], 2014-06-03=[2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4]}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer Tobias. Unfortunately my output doesn't match the same form as above. Everything comes out as follows

`{2014-06-02=[0.1234]}
{2014-06-02=[0.5678]}
{2014-06-02=[0.9101]}`

The only thing I'm doing different is adding the necessary data to the Map, like so:

`for(int i = 0; i < datesList.size(); i++)
{
 ungroupedCsv.put(dates.get(i), doubleList.get(i));
}`

Comment: @HarryV Are you sure the rest of the code is the same? Your output looks like you are printing in each iteration of the loop, and like you re-initialize the `grouped` map in each iteration, as well, thus holding just the latest item. Or, instead of appending to the list, maybe you are replacing the list in the loop?

Comment: I have a feeling that it could be how I am adding the keys and values to the map. In my code I have a list which holds all the double values. I also have another list which holds all the dates as strings. To add them to the Map I do the following:
for(int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {ungroupedCsv.put(dates.get(i), doubleValues.get(i));}

After that the code is exactly the same! Although I wrapped the for loop in a try-catch block.

Comment: @HarryV Frankly, I have no idea... does it work when you use my exact same code, including the test values map? Is there any exception cought in your catch block? And do those three `{...}` outputs from your first comment appear on separate lines?

Comment: I did one test with your exact code, and your test values and it worked. For the catch block I'm just using a ParseException. As for the outputs from my first comment, they all appear on separate lines, yes. It seems the only difference is when I'm using a for loop to add the keys and values from different ArrayLists into the map. If there is some way to send the full code to you I'm happy to do that.

Comment: @HarryV If they appear on separate lines that means that you run the code in a loop. Did you put it in the same for loop you use to populate the `ungroupedCsv` map? (You shouldn't.) If that's not the problem, please append your exact code as an edit to/below your original question so I can have a look.

Comment: Eureka! You were right, I had the code running inside a while loop. I need the while loop to go through the CSV file until I reach the end. I just re arranged the code and declared some lists outside the while loop instead of inside and now I'm good to go. Thanks for all your help Tobias, much appreciated.